# Adding "Soft Delete" to an existing system

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, cascading-deletes, soft-delete

I have a system which contains a lot of stored procedures, functions which run of `TableA`, for example. We need a way of being able to delete these orders, but keeping them on record.

One option we've considered is having a `Delete` field in `TableA` then go through all the sprocs and functions adding:

```
WHERE Deleted=0
```

Another option we've considered is creating a view called something like `v_TableA` then going through and changing all the sprocs and functions to read from this view, rather than the table.

Both involve a lot of work, and will need to be remembered when making future changes to the system.

I'm hoping there is a better way of doing this something like:

```
SOFTDELETE FROM TableA
```

But I know this isn't possible. Any help would be much appreciated.